# Populating all the data from GeoJSON to an HTML div

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, web-mapping

I have GeoJSON and I am trying to get all the data from it and display it on a div element.
This is what I have been able to do so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-3" id="graphs">
```

**JS**

```
Layer= L.geoJson(response, {
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
            }
        }).addTo(map);
```

The `OnEachFeature` function

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer){
    var properties = feature.properties;
    var content = [];
    for (var key in properties) {
         if (key == "Province")
               content.push(key + ': ' + properties[key]);
    }
    
    $("#graphs").html(content);

    
}
```

The problem is that `$("#graphs").html(content);` links only the last element to the div. I am hoping to populate all the data. I have tried adding the data through for loop but that doesn't work either.

I am not looking for onclick functions. That I am aware of. I want this data when the GeoJSON loads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you set `$("graphs").html()` to each element in turn, overwriting the previous content.

Use `$("graphs").append(content);`, that should retain the previous content, or whatever jquery function fits your needs. This really is a jquery question, and not a GIS question.

See jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h89Los6t/ for code.

See https://api.jquery.com/append/ for the jquery documentation for append.

Comment: Thanks but this is giving me an empty div.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works now.